# Delphi - callback wrong code

Tags: delphi, callback, frame

I believe I'm too tired, and I don't understand why a small callback doesn't work. I have 2 frames, created dynamically, I show the first one and at a click, I show the second one. When I finish the work with the second one, I want to show the first frame and free the second frame. Code is bellow:

code for the first frame:

```
procedure CommingBackFromFrame(aFrame:TFrame);

procedure TfraMain.ComingBackFromFrame(aFrame:TFrame);
begin
 if Assigned(aFrame) then
 begin
 try
   aFrame.Hide;
   FreeAndNil(aFrame);
  except on e:Exception do
//make a log
  end;
 Self.Show;//first frame show
 end;



//code which creates the second frame
    wFrm := TFrameType.Create(Application);//create the second frame
      with wFrm do
      begin
        GoBack:=ComingBackFromFrame(wFrm);//error here
        parent:=Self;
        Show;
      end; //with
      Application.ProcessMessages;
```

code for the second frame:

```
 TCallBack = procedure(aFrame:TFrame) of object;//callback declaration 
  TFrameType = class(Tframe)
...
  private
    FGoBack:TCallBack;
  public
    property GoBack:TCallBack read FGoBack write FGoBack;//publish callback
....
//at a moment, return to frame 1

 if Assigned(fgoback) then
 GoBack(Self);
```

Can anyone help me this simple thing?

Comment: It is never a wise thing to free the parameter of an event method; the underlying object might still be in use somewhere in the call stack. I'm not sure there is a 'release' for frames (like it is for forms), but you should do something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to all.Thank you for your answers, especially to Abelisto et Jeroen, I've resolved now all the problems. Until Abelisto suggested PostMessage I've encountered lots of errors. Entire solution is bellow :

first frame, or FrmMain :

```
const WM_MY_MESSAGE = WM_USER + 0;
type
TfraMain = class(TFrame)
...
private 
  FFraChild        : TFraChild;//second frame
  procedure OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage); message WM_MY_MESSAGE;
  procedure ComingBackFromFrame(aFrame:TFrame);
....
//step when the second frame is created 
  FFraChild := TFraChild.Create(Application);
  with FFraChild do
  begin
    GoBack:= ComingBackFromFrame;
    parent:=Self;
    Show;  
  end; //with
....
procedure TfraMain.ComingBackFromFrame(aFrame:TFrame);
begin
 if aFrame<>nil then
 begin
 try
   aFrame.Hide;
   PostMessage(Self.Handle,WM_MY_MESSAGE,0,0);
  except on e:Exception do
//   log error
  end;
 end;
end;

procedure TfraMain.OnMyMessage(var Msg: TMessage);
begin
 FreeAndNil(FFraChild);
end;
```

second frame or frame 'child'

```
type
  TCallBack = procedure(aFrame:TFrame) of object;

  TFraChild = class(TFrame)
...
  private
    FGoBack:TCallBack;
  public
    property GoBack:TCallBack read FGoBack write FGoBack;
....
//after all operations with it are finished 
 if Assigned(fgoback) then
  FGoBack(Self);
```

@Jeroen, I didn't found something related to Frames as the 'Release' existing in the TForm's implementation.

Best regards,

Radu

Comment: +1 for solving your issue. For your information: `Release` uses a `PostMessage` mechanism too.

Comment: now who deserves the accept :)) you gave me a partial solution and Abelisto and CodeInChaos the other part....

Answer (score 4):

BTW this is bad practice - free an object from its own code. Try to do that by message handler via PostMessage() to ensure that VCL finished all its work before freeing object.
Something like this:

```
TFrameType = class(TFrame)
protected
    procedure FreeMe(var Msg TMessage) message WM_FREE_MY_FRAME;
public
    procedure PostponedFree;
end;

procedure TFrameType.FreeMe(var Msg TMessage);
begin
    Free;
end;

procedure TFrameType.PostponedFree;
begin
    PostMessage(Self.Handle, WM_FREE_MY_FRAME, 0, 0);
end;
```

And call `PostponedFree`.
PS Code may not be accurate - I haven't started Delphi now. Sorry.

Comment: Yes, bad idea. That's what is happening when I'm too tired and still need to code.Unfortunately, I can't do +2.... :) Thank you.

Comment: Alternatively there is the Release method which has been added for exactly that purpose.

Answer (score 3):

You're calling `CommingBackFromFrame`. So unless it's return-type is `TCallBack` it's obvious that it doesn't compile.

You might want to do  `GoBack:=CommingBackFromFrame;` instead which subscribes the method `CommingBackFromFrame` to the even `GoBack`. Or perhaps `GoBack:=wFrm.CommingBackFromFrame;` depending on where `CommingBackFromFrame` is declared.

SideNote: You have a typo, the word is "coming" and not `comming`

Comment: I've edited the question to contain the declaration of the 'coming' method.

Answer (score 2):

Specify where `CommingBackFromFrame` comes from and what it does; without that, CodeInChaos` [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836713/delphi-callback-wrong-code/4836731#4836731) is the best you can get.

Is it part of `wFrmDblDet`, or part of your encompassing scope (the usage of `with` obfuscates that)?

In your current code, `ComingBackFromFrame(wFrm)` should return a `TCallBack`, but I think that was not your intent.

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks Jeroen. I want to free the second frame after I finish working with it.